# Teradata Python: teradata.api.InterfaceError

Tags: python, python-2.7, odbc, teradata, execute

I have a simple select query from a python script to select data from Teradata DB shown below,

session.execute("select distinct v_column from a_table where a_column in (?)",(value))

Value in this case is a tuple with values derived from other bunch of queries.

This query works just fine if I pass in the one value from the variable. For anything more than 1 - I had to change my query to contain more place holders like this (?,?).

I wanted to make this dynamic or generic place holder that can work irrespective. I tried few options and does not seem to make sense to me. Any better suggestions ?

Error with single placeholder with more than one value:
teradata.api.InterfaceError: ('PARAMS_MISMATCH', 'The number of supplied parameters (2) does not match the expected number of parameters (1).')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it worked using the new way of working with place holders `"{}".format()`

Working Query:

```
session.execute("select distinct v_column from a_table where a_column in{}".format(value))
```

Comment: any chance you could help with teradata python parameters? I'm having a very challenging time passing them...